# Gap in the concept of implicit Ordering of a type used to create a Collection

Tags: scala, scala-collections, implicit-declaration

Forgive me if the solution to this problem is too obvious or has been resolved already in this forum earlier (in which case, please point me to the post).

I have a class

```
org.personal.exercises.LengthContentsPair (l: Int, c: String) 
{
    val length = l
    val contents = c

}
```

Then, in the same source file, I also define an implicit value which defines the way objects
of this type is to be ordered, thus:

```
object LengthContentsPair  {

    implicit val lengthContentsPairOrdering = new Ordering [LengthContentsPair] {

       def compare (a: LengthContentsPair, b: LengthContentsPair)= {
   
          a.length compare b.length;
       }
    }
 }
```

following solutions given in this forum.

Now, I want to create a specialized Set which limits the number of elements in the Set to a given number. So, I define a separate class like this:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet;

import org.personal.exercises.LengthContentsPair.lengthContentsPairOrdering;

class FixedSizedSortedSet [LengthContentsPair]  extends TreeSet [LengthContentsPair]  
{ .. 
}
```

To me, this seems the correct way to subclass a TreeSet. But, the compiler throws the following error:

> (1) No implicit Ordering defined for LengthContentsPair.
>
> (2) not enough arguments for constructor TreeSet: (implicit ordering: Ordering[LengthContentsPair])scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[LengthContentsPair]. Unspecified value parameter ordering.

Have I understood the scoping rules wrongly? It is something quite easy I feel, but I cannot put my hand on it.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `FixedSizedSortedSet` wrong. Your implementation has generic type parameter named `LengthContentsPair` which has nothing to do with your class with that name. In other words, you have shadowed `LengthContentsPair` class with generic type.

If you need a specialized set that only holds elements of `LengthContentsPair`, then you probably meant:

```
class FixedSizedSortedSet extends TreeSet[LengthContentsPair]  
{ .. 
}
```

This should work if an instance of `Ordering[LengthContentsPair]` is visible. But this shouldn't be a problem, since the ordering is defined in companion object of `LengthContentsPair` and is visible as implicit parameter by default.

But if you rather need a generic extension of `TreeSet` which can hold elements of any type, then you probably meant this:

```
class FixedSizedSortedSet[T](implicit ordering: Ordering[T]) extends TreeSet[T]  
{ .. 
}
```

Implicit parameter is needed because `TreeSet` requires an implicit `Ordering[T]`, so we need to forward that requirement to `FixedSizedSortedSet`

BTW. I'd suggest you to consider replacing your `LengthContentsPair` class with a [case class](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/107).

Comment: Gosh! I berate myself for being blind to the shadow effect. How could I miss that and spend at least an hour looking at the code. Many thanks for spotting. And, yes, in my source code, LengthContentsPair is indeed a 'case class' because I have lot of matches to do.